# Uploading and Publishing Raster file (*.tiff) on Geo server but getting 'No Layer' Error

Tags: geoserver

Uploading and Publishing Raster file (*.tiff) on Geo server but getting 'No Layer' Error.
I am trying to create a layer for NDVI data and tried to upload it manually, in this case, its store and layer were created but I was not able to get its layer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: is the uploading path too long or containing non-ascii characters? what system are you using Linux/Windows? Could be a permission issue also. It will be good to share the log files.